# React Native CLI Emulator Shutting Down

Tags: react-native

I am getting a weird error or maybe bug when running react native cli using `yarn android`. I have checked everything and even re-installed my java sdk and all the android sdk's. Also for some reason when i run `npx reactnative-doctor` i see an error that my android studio is not downloaded.

[React Native Doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yeSE.png)

I tried doing all the the configurations

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Please share the details of the error you encountered, and attempt to build the app using Android Studio. Open the 'android/' directory in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Also platform tools should be edited to path:

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

If the above paths are okay then try:

For windows

**cd android**

**gradlew clean**

For IOS

**cd android**

**chmod +x gradlew**

**./gradlew clean**